# PHP convert signed 64-bit integer to hex and back

Tags: php, integer-overflow

On a 64-bit system, off course. I would rather not use bcmath, but I think it to be necessary:

Test code, that works, but returns the output as 64-bit *unsigned* integer and overflows (PHP doesn't support 64-bit unsigned integers).

```
var_dump(-3172679146711529273);
var_dump(dechex(-3172679146711529273));
var_dump(hexdec(dechex(-3172679146711529273)));
```

will return:

```
int(-3172679146711529273)
string(16) "d3f8612029f848c7"
float(1.5274064926998E+19)
```

An alternative would be to pack the integer into another format (base 36?).

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: PHP support signed ints without a problem... but [`dechex`  does _not_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php), it suspects unsigned ones. An obvious alternative [`base_convert` goes to float internally](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php). So, the issue becomes: do you just need to do math on signed 64 bit ints, or do you really need their hexadecimal representation? The answers to those 2 are quite different.